# Not allowed by CORS

Tags: api, postman, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to automate a process so I want to connect to an external API, first just to log in (can't use the API Key since I'm not an admin user).

I basically copied the request the browser does when it logs in, but when doing this from Postman I get a 400 responde, with the body "Not allowed by CORS".

Is there any way through code, that I can bypass that and work with such API?

[image: The postman request]

Answer (score 0):

Cors means Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. Basically browsers help web servers a way to protect themselves for data change requests.

Remove `Origin` Header (or) replace `Origin` value to server hostname (in this case `api.kenjo.io`)

Add referer header.
With [dothttp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShivaPrasanth.dothttp-code) it would look like below.

```
POST 'https://api.kenjo.io/auth/token'
origin: 'https://www.kenjo.io'
referer: 'https://www.kenjo.io/'
```

Comment: I added it and still returns the same :(

Comment: If possible can you share your all headers here .

Comment: They are exactly the ones of the picture (plus the ones postman adds)